# LWJGL moving/rotating objects

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, rendering, lwjgl

I recently started a project in lwjgl using gl11 and it is able to project 3d objects onto the screen. But as soon as I try to rotate/translate an object, it just disappears​ or is just visible when between z=0 and z=2
[source code](https://mega.nz/#!U0IgjR4J!lzpd8NfIUJRWJHhUcMOFceqhNtwNA_1UUYnRzn-XIEA)

Here's my draw method:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glTranslatef(position.x, position.y, position.z);

glRotatef(rotation.z,0,0,1);
glRotatef(rotation.y,0,1,0);
glRotatef(rotation.x,1,0,0);

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

for(GLData d : data) {
    glColor4f(d.r,d.g,d.b,d.a);
    glVertex3f(d.x,d.y,d.z);
}

glEnd();
```

Comment: Try rotating first, then translate

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: Have you tried glPushMatrix()?  As a recommendation, I would try to move away from the early, fixed functionality pipeline of early OpenGL and move towards 3.1+, when the modern pipeline really took off.

Comment: pushMatrix and popMatrix don't change anything because I don't use any other modelView matrices. Maybe I'll change this project to a newer gl version. but now I want to figure out why this is not working